# Laravel Email Verification From API is not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to verify the email with API but I always get "Invalid/Expired url provided.".

From the email I got a verification URL like

```
http://localhost:8000/email/verify/9/36be72d64a3dfec027a14bc40cea3e76424dea05?expires=1620495480&signature=59aef4e96a56e4fa8e6ebcdf3c9e3ebef2eac5f21190c6baa8ae30d17e2fbee9
```

and on postman I try to send a request like below I get invalid signature error

```
http://localhost:8000/api/verify-email/9?expires=1620495480&hash=36be72d64a3dfec027a14bc40cea3e76424dea05&signature=59aef4e96a56e4fa8e6ebcdf3c9e3ebef2eac5f21190c6baa8ae30d17e2fbee9
```

Routes

```
Route::get( '/verify-email/{id}', [
    \App\Http\Controllers\ApiAuth\VerifyEmailController::class,
    'index'
] )->name( 'verification.verify' );
```

Controller

```
public function index($user_id, Request $request) {
    if (!$request->hasValidSignature()) {
        return response(["success"=> false, "message" => "Invalid/Expired url provided."], 401);
    }

    $user = User::find($user_id);
    if(!$user) {
        return response(["success"=> false, "message" => "Invalid User"], 401);
    }

    if (!$user->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
        $user->markEmailAsVerified();
        return response(["success"=> true] );
    }else {
        return response(["success"=> true, "message" => "Email Already Verified"] );
    }
}
```